# Why I can't access local file after deploy using IE browser?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, html5-canvas

After my system deploy, I can't access local file. I'm using IE-11 and what i know.  IE enable to access local file not like the other browser.I can access local file when debugging in development environment but the link doesn't function after my system deploy. Can somebody let me know why this happen.

**Using href:**

```
<li><a href="file://fileshare/FILE_SHAREZ/IT"  target="_blank"><i style="font-size:16px" class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> IT Fileshare</a></li>
```

**Using javascript:**

```
<li><a onclick="myFunction()"><i style="font-size:16px" class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> IT Fileshare</a></li>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            window.open('file://fileshare/FILE_SHAREZ/IT', '_blank');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Does the webserver you've deployed to have the same access to that network share as your dev pc?

Comment: okay , thank you @83N maybe that why

Comment: @83N i already check, my webserver that I've already deployed have the same access to the network as dev pc. The other old system also can access but why my system can't .Its because of Asp.net?

Comment: Check that the identity the Application Pool is running under in IIS is also permissioned to access that share... It sounds like a permissions issue if you are able to see it but your code is not